# ctypes own library loads but can't access functions/methods

Tags: python, c++, linux, ctypes

I am trying to write a c routine to speed up a python script.

In order to route prove my method I first wrote a short test c function and compiled it into a library: the code for the test function is:

```
void cttest(void);
#include <stdio.h>

void cttest()
{
    printf("This is the shared module|n");
    return;
}
```

I saved this code into a file 'ct_test.cc'.

I then compiled this code as follows:

```
g++ -shared -fPIC -o /home/paula/libs/libcttest.so ct_test.cc
```

which gave no errors or warnings.

I then loaded ipython and typed the following:

```
import ctypes as ct

test=ct.CDLL("/home/paula/libs/libcttest.so")
```

if I now try to access the function (by typing 'test.' and then hitting tab) nothing happens.

If I do this:

What am I doing wrong?

Oh, just in case it makes any difference:

OS: xubuntu 14.10
Python: 2.7.8
ipython: 2.3.0
g++ : 4.9.1

Comment: The syntax used at https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#loading-dynamic-link-libraries is different. You could try their suggestion.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to comment and for your suggestion. I have now tried the 'cdll.LoadLibrary' syntax and the result is the same.

Comment: Type `test.cttest()`.  Don't assume tab-completion works.

Comment: Using C++, the name stored in the library will differ from just 'cttest' (there's name mangling). To prevent this, add `extern "C" ` just before your first line to inform g++ that the C-style name should be stored instead.

Comment: Thankyou to Mark Tolonen and brm for the replies.

Mark, I tried both, neither worked. I will try brm's suggestion next.  Thakyou both once again.

Comment: I am delighted to tell you all that brm is right! Thankyou all for your help

Comment: eryksun, Thankyou for your comment. I would merely point out that, as R Sahu says, the documentation, in its examples, uses cdll.LoadLibrary. I must confess I find the reasons for this incomprehensible for precisely the reasons you state. I do however feel obliged to point out that not all of us use Windows so "kernel32" is not known to some of us.

Comment: Sorry, using kernel32 was a bad example given this is tagged Linux. The `__getattr__` usage such as `cdll.msvcrt` is only applicable to Windows. On Linux demonstrating the caching problem requires using `__getitem__`, e.g. `cdll['/home/paula/libs/libcttest.so']`. This can lead to prototype collisions across modules. Using `cdll.LoadLibrary` calls `CDLL` without caching, but you may as well call `CDLL` directly.

Comment: Well I didn't expand the comments before answering so missed that it was solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. Firstly as has already been noted tab auto-complete won't work for ctypes until a function has been used for the first time. (It wouldn't be impossible to make it work on most platforms, but it would add a fair overhead to loading the library I suspect).
2. You've written C and you're trying to call it like C, but you used a C++ compiler so you have a name mangling problem.

The solution to the first problem is trivial - use the full name and don't rely on auto-completion. There are at least 3 solutions to the second, I've written them here from best to worst:

1. Use a C compiler instead of C++ compiler. (`gcc` instead of `g++`).
2. [Use `extern "C"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c) to force the C++ compiler to not mangle the function name:

   ```
   extern "C" void cttest(void);

   extern "C" 
   {
       void cttest()
       {
           printf("This is the shared module\n");
           return;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use the mangled C++ name in Python, in this case it would be `_Z6cttestv`

To prove that this works I tried it out on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -o libcttest.so test.c
```

And using it in ipython:

```py
ipython
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:38) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import ctypes as ct

In [2]: test=ct.CDLL('./libcttest.so')

In [3]: test.cttest()
This is the shared module
Out[3]: 26
```